# Is 500 lines too big for a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a Table component that has filters on it and therefore there is a lot of logic involved and also I am using material ui which uses a lot of lines. However I am finding the component to be too extense. Is having a component with this size ok?

Comment: I imagine it's entirely up to you. If it's well documented and maintainable for your team, go for it. But it's a very non-definitively answerable question, where preference is the solution, so ... good luck!

Comment: The question is off-topic on SO. it's opinion-based. The answer is that it depends. Considering that you're asking it, it's probably too big, otherwise you would be certain that you're doing the right thing. Consider asking at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Let your experience guide you. If you feel something is too large, try breaking it down and see if it helps. This is what source control branches are for. Splitting things up isn't a law, it's a guideline.

Answer (score 3):

This is mostly a matter of personal choice.

In my opinion, I would say no. I try to keep my components as small as possible.

Try breaking down your component into smaller components that you find are re-used lots.

Otherwise, if your component is well-documented, I would say 500 lines is okay.

It mostly depends on what the component is and the complexity of it.

It's totally up to you though!